# How can I talk about the "gypsy aesthetic" without using the word "gypsy"?

Tags: single-word-requests, political-correctness

The term "gypsy" was embraced with a lot of positivity by many counter-cultural groups in the US; namely hippies.  Many grew up with the term meaning nothing negative, but -- as it turns out -- there are many places where it known better as a slur.  Enough that it's no longer acceptable language for professional contexts.

The issue I'm running into is that I can't find a suitable replacement.  See these search results:

**Query: "Romanian Aesthetic"**

[image]

---

**Query: "Gypsy Aesthetic"**

[image]

---

**Query: "Hippy Aesthetic"**

[image]

As you can see, there is a very distinct style and aesthetic that is given to the term "gypsy."  It's a very western, sort of hippy spiritual, flowy clothing, earth tones and jewelry thing.  But I can find no synonym.

I've tried: Romanian American, Hippy Festival, Hippy Traveler, Vagabond, Bohemian, Bohemian Hippy (closest), Nomad, Nomad Hippy, Nomad Bohemian.... none sound correct to me, nor yield correct results based off common usage (ie google image search).

**How can I refer to this set of aesthetics without using what I consider to be a racial slur?**

Comment: *Bohemian* is the word in current usage for the style. Try searching `"bohemian style"`. Or `"boho style"`.

Comment: What context are you wanting to use it in? Academic study, social media posts about your new 'fit, or something else?

Comment: @TinfoilHat, `boho` and `bohemian` are pretty far off if you do an image search.  It's kind of an upper-class aesthetic in my experience.

@StuartF, I was hoping to do an introductory series of classes on sewing centered around the sort of things I've seen at festivals that I've only ever heard described as "gypsy clothing."  There's a sort of home-made but still beautiful aspect that I think renders itself well to new learners.

Comment: Are you saying that the right pictures come up for an image search of `"gypsy aesthetic"` but that you are looking for a different term that brings up those or similar pictures?

Comment: I'm using image search as a way to check if *other people* will understand the term I'm using.  I've only got a tiny bit of space on a calendar to advertise the class, so being succinct and understandable goes a long way.

Comment: While I appreciate your reasons for regarding *hippy* as not quite right for your purposes, it may, as a practical matter, be the best available one (particularly given that you have accepted the answer that effectively says that the term you are seeking does not exist). Retired hippies are unlikely to be offended. Note also that there is a term *hippyish* that one may want to use if one wants to make it clearer that the concept in question is vague (although that term may not be suitable for a formal context).

Comment: You seem to have confused 'Romanian' with 'Romany'. Whilst there is a Romany population in Romania, the country is not named after them but after it being a Roman colony. It's a bit like confusing Austria and Australia. (I have enough Roma blood in me that I couldn't get served in restaurants in Romania and my blonde wife had to go in first to get us a table, the Romanian witch in your search is may well be practicing https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zalmoxianism - a entho-religion explicitly excluding Roma)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As [an article in Vogue about the fashion industry](https://www.vogue.com/article/roma-activism-fashion) explains, the aesthetic *itself* is considered offensive by many Romani (not Romanian!) people, perhaps even moreso than the word "gypsy" itself:

> The hashtag #gypsystyle has 1.2 million posts with a mishmash of cultures, including Mexican Day of the Dead outfits, Arabic belly dancer costumes, and Indian wedding dresses. But some themes do recur. There are a lot of white women in dreads and/or turbans and beachside photoshoots featuring crochet bikinis and lace dresses. It seems anything that denotes an unconventional, well-traveled, and sexy life qualifies as “gypsy.”
>
> “Mainstream fashion took a lot of elements from Roma culture (free-flowing dresses, use of coins as ornamentation, rose motifs, dikhlos, etc.) and never really acknowledged their origin,” says Erika Varga, the Roma designer behind high-end label Romani Design. “But most of the time it is just an imitation of Roma wear built on stereotypes.”
>
> Grigore cannot bring herself to go down the #gypsystyle rabbithole of Instagram. “People love the Gypsy culture, but they completely ignore the Roma life,” she says. “You're taking people's suffering. It looks so good on you, so cute.”
>
> Far from being a compliment, these Gypsy-themed fashion shoots hamper Roma advancement. “Think about me going to, let's say, Congress, to talk about the Roma plight,” Grigore says. “And they say, ‘Ah, beautiful clothes and parties!’ You cannot make a serious argument when you have the culture so objectified and treated this like a cute little thing, like a pet.”

Given that fact, you really won't be able to find a positive way of describing this aesthetic that *won't* risk offending Romani people. It would be hard to find an inoffensive way of praising something so deeply rooted in anti-Romani stereotypes.

Comment: To quote the article: "Call it luxury circus style, boho-chic, or beach vibes. Just don’t call it Gypsy style."  Given a few searches, none of these terms have taken root yet.  Perhaps they will in the future.

Comment: Isn't there a tension between treating the term *Gipsy* as problematic and using the term *antiziganist*?

Comment: @LibrarySeph The main issue is that those other terms don't refer to quite the same thing as "gypsy style," though there is some overlap.

Comment: @alphabet, it is true that many Romani people do not object to such terms in other languages, but some do, and it is also true that, as Greybeard's answer shows, not all Romani object to the use of *Gipsy* in English (note that the Wikipedia article you cite says that it 'is considered pejorative by **some** Romani people'). It is far from obvious that the implications and associations carried by *Gipsy* in English are very much different from those carried by the corresponding terms in continental-European languages.

Answer (score 3):

The OED was updated in March 2023 and has the following:

> **Romani**, n. and adj.
>
> **A. n.
>
> 1. A member of a widely dispersed ethnic group, found mainly in Europe and North and South America, tracing its origins to South Asia; = Rom n.2**   Cf. Gypsy n. 1a.
>
> 2003   N.Y. Mag. 21 Apr. 30/1   *Called Gypsies because they were erroneously thought to have come from Egypt, the Romani..claim to trace their origin to the Rajput princes of India.*

There is no note to advise on the use of Roma/Romani - which there would be if it were offensive. It is a term widely used in respectable and responsible publications in the UK.

I also think that you are being far too vicariously sensitive about the use of Gypsy: [The Gypsy Council of Great Britain](https://www.romaniarts.co.uk/tag/gypsy-council/) (which has similarly named representatives in many other countries) is the body that represents their interests and those of Roma.

Neither is "Gypsy" a racial slur.

Comment: I have to be extremely careful with things like this when representing the my organization (a Library in this case).  But it is interesting to see that OED has a definition more in line with the usage I've heard and used throughout my life.  Thanks for sharing this.

Comment: @LibrarySeph I suggest you get in touch with your local/National Gypsy Council and take their advice. Any ill-informed criticism can then be dismissed.

Comment: The OED won't protect you if someone takes offense, and there are people who take offense. Do with that what you will.

Answer (score 0):

Prefer "Romani style". Roma is the broadly accepted name of the ethnic group otherwise called Gypsies, a name which stuck when the Romani people of northern India migrated to Europe and were mistaken for Egyptians. The name Gypsy is considered offensive by some for the historic sense of oppression it conveys and the failure of the term to testify to the history of the Romani people.

Comment: This may be an apt term for a style that has its roots in actual Romani culture; its use would require that the speaker know enough about that culture to discern how what it's applied to is related to it. *Gipsy style* is, however, a term that is, as the other answer points out, often used for things that fit the speaker's vague ideas about that culture, that may not be based on any genuine appreciation of it.

Comment: The name *Gypsy* has gone through a considerable metamorphosis in Britain, as I feel sure it has in other European countries. Up to some point in the early 20th century a very large number of the people comprising itinerant groups in Britain, who were called gypsies, were in fact of ethnic "gypsy" descent and many spoke the Romany language. However the similarly travelling groups that exist today are comprised of all kinds of people and the Romany language is not nearly as widely used among them. (continued)

Comment: Partly as a reflection of this change, and partly to avoid offense they are now mostly described as "travellers". There are also offensive terms that are used for them by the less than respectable in society. The Roma or Romani are groups that are perhaps related to the ethnic gypsy population, who have migrated to Britain mostly from the Balkan regions of Europe.